# AngularJS + Jersey RESTful backend: Authentication & Authorization

Tags: angularjs, jersey, restful-authentication

I'm building an AngularJS web-app that uses Jersey as a RESTful ws provider. I want users to be able to login and only perform certain operations. Should I use OAuth for this? I've seen people mentioning OAuth a lot in the context of offering third parties an opportunity to access data in your backend that belongs to some users (e.g Facebook login), but in this case it will just be me, my frontend making calls to my backend.

Before, I used to do this with JSF and CDI, but I decided to switch to Angular, so now my backend and frontend are not as "glued-together" as they used to be. Should I use OAuth for this use case? Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a loosely coupled API that might be used from other frontends and/or services OAuth is certainly the way to go in my opinion. It can save you a lot of cross domain headaches as well (IE9 won't allow cookies, authentication etc. to be included in cross domain requests for instance).

If you're absolutely sure it's only going to be your own frontend, I'd consider placing the API in the same web application, which would solve authentication by using the same as the frontend.